# Input field causes overflow of containing div

Tags: html, css

Why does this input field causes an overflow of containing div

My css code is as follows:

```css
input, textarea, select {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {
    border-color: #66AFE9;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075), 0px 0px 8px rgba(102,175,233,0.60);
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" style="width:100%"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

why the input field causes overflow of the containing div element?

Comment: `width: 100%` + padding  + border = >100% width - add: `input { box-sizing: border-box; }` which will include the border and padding in the 100% width.

Comment: Indeed adding box-sizing:border-box solved it